# Same meaning and different outputs

Tags: assembly, nasm

I've been recently studying the 80x86 assembly language with nasm. However, one of those codes that i've been working on pops up an error! Unfortunately, i don't understand why... Would you give me a hand?

**.data and .bss**

```
segment .data
minho dd 100
ilseob dd 200

segment .bss
extern _hello
extern _hello2
```

**first .text with no error.**

```
mov eax, [minho]
mov [_hello], eax
mov eax, [ilseob]
mov [_hello2], eax
```

**second .text with an error.**

```
mov dword[_hello], [minho]
mov dword[_hello2], [ilseob]

invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

Because i'm a newbie in assembly language, there might be a mistake or a mis-understanding...

Comment: As a general rule, two memory operands are not allowed. Do it the first way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mem,mem` is not a valid combination of operands for `MOV`. That is, there's no variant of `MOV` that moves data directly from memory to memory.

Consult [the instruction set reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) when you're in doubt over which operands you can use.

Comment: @JesusPlusPlus11 Oh...sorry! I just checked it. Thank you again!